Windows 10 Search Bar - Multiple Application Icons not working properly
Steam,OBS Studio, League of legends icons not showing properly and unclickable
Problem: Icons not working properly and also unclickable.
My Tried Solution: I already tried rebuilding the search index options but did not work. I also tried the tests on this link (Icons not showing in windows 10 search) but to no avail these application still showing and unclickable. I also tried the screen scaling from 125% to 100% to see if this fixes the application but it still show this problem is there any fix to this kind of thing? I also updated my computer if that also fix it but no it is also not working. what is the problem with this I will also try to reinstall but if this icon still show I think I will lose my mind.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you find the entries in the Start Menu (not using Search) are you able to open them? Some update/patch installers change the location of the exe, usually to a version-specific folder, and these will often break pinned shortcuts. When you right-click on these "broken" shortcuts, can you click Open File Location, and does it take you to a valid location?
